# Android Studio 0.8.9 Emulator Issues

Tags: android, emulation

Would anyone know why my application on my emulator is not updating with my code? Along with that, when I have the emulator running and I try to rerun the program it does not recognize there is already an emulator running.  I figure these two issues are related.

Fixes I have attempted to of no avail:

- Reset ADB
- Uninstall the app on the emulator and rerun program but as I said above the emulator is not recognized.  Now I just don't have the app on my emulator anymore.
- I have also tried to use the Device Monitor - for an emulator but again, the emulator is not recognized even though it is running.
- Reinstalled android studio

Any advice will be helpful.